How do i become a MC marketplace creator?
I am in desperate need of Minecoins for an add-on, and I want to publish a bunker map me and my friend have been working on, so what do I do???

Hi Noah, welcome to Arqade! What have you tried/found yourself so far? What exactly are you struggling with? What do Minecoins or Doomsday Bunker maps have to do with you becoming a marketplace creator?

Well, i dont want to buy any minecoins, so i would publish a map and hopefully people would like it, and buy it, they could test if the bunkers NUKE proof, and stuff I just want minecoins, I could be a HALFTIME creator though

@NoahS It seems you are using a different account to interact on this post. To regain access to your old account, merge your two accounts by following the procedure described in the Help Center.

To upload things to the Marketplace you need to become a partner. Applications are currently closed, and it seems to be more for businesses than independent creators. You're also paid in money, not Minecoins (because businesses want to be paid). More information can be found on the Partner Program page.
I'd recommend you just buy Minecoins if you want them. It's far cheaper and easier than becoming a partner.
